# How can I Check how many queries a LinqToSql DataContext ran?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, datacontext

Is there any way I can check how many DB queries a `DataContext` ran?

I know I can run an `sql profiler` but I want to analyze a big project with hundreds of queries.

If not, is there any useful event that I can register to and count them?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
using(DataContext ctx = new DataContext(connectionString))
{
    // Add load options
    // execute a query 

    // I want information about the number of actual sql queries that ran using this context. 
    // Adding "1 to many" loadoptions or complex queries can create multiple sub-queries and that's why I want this info.
}
```

Comment: Check out tools like: Miniprofiler http://miniprofiler.com/

Comment: @jessehouwing - Thanks for the tip. I'll check out the external package if there is no way to do this in house. I would expect the framework to provide me this information in one way or another.

Comment: look at the code of miniprofiler to see how they do it :) https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/tree/master/StackExchange.Profiling.EntityFramework6

Comment: @jessehouwing - Nice..I'll check it out..Thanks! BTW I'm stuck with Linq2Sql..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LINQ to SQL you have the option to log the generated SQL to a `TextWriter`. For instance you can log to the console:

```
ctx.Log = Console.Out;
```

This will not give you a count of queries but it will provide you with the actual SQL executed which probably gives you a better insight into what is going on.

If you want to provide an aggregated view of say the number of select statements you can log to a `StringWriter` and then use regular expressions to count the number of occurences of the word `SELECT`:

```
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
ctx.Log = stringWriter;

// Use DataContext referenced by ctx ...

var regex = new Regex(@"\bSELECT\b");
var selectCount = regex.Matches(stringWriter.ToString()).Count;
```

Obviously, you may have to also count other words like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` and you may run into counting problems if you have say a `WHERE` clause containing the word `SELECT`.

Instead of trying to "understand" the SQL to make a count you can count the number of SQL statements executed. Each statement ends with a line that in my tests have the following format:

```
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.34209
```

You can create a regular expression to match this string:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^-- Context: ", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var statementCount = regex.Matches(stringWriter.ToString()).Count;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I know that I can actually see the queries. My problem is that If I load "1 to many" sub-tables, lots of sub queries can get executed. Will they get logged as well? Or will I see the same "main query" as I can see using ctx.ToString()?

Comment: @AmirPopovich: All activities performed by the `DataContext` is logged using the current value of the `Log` property so you if you set this property before executing your main query and inspect the output after all your queries have completed you will see everything executed against the server.

Comment: +1 Wow, that's pretty nice. I'll check this out later in my code.
To bad they didn't provide a counter as well.

Comment: @AmirPopovich: I have updated my answer to demonstrate how you can count the number of SQL statements executed which may be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I've tested you code and it works great so thanks for that. I'm bummed that .net didn't add something built in and light since calculating this on each context is pretty heavy. Thanks!!!